# Computing the sum in a joined table in Apache Pig

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, apache-pig

I load the following three tables from Hive:

```
books   = LOAD 'books'   USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() AS (isbn_b: chararray, booktitle: chararray, author: chararray, pubyear: chararray, publisher: chararray, urls: chararray, urlm: chararray, urll: chararray);
users   = LOAD 'users'   USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() AS (id_u: chararray, location: chararray, age: chararray);
ratings = LOAD 'ratings' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() AS (id_r: chararray, isbn_r: chararray, rating: chararray);
```

and I join and group them as follows:

```
OnISBN    = JOIN  ratings BY isbn_r, books BY isbn_b;
total     = JOIN  OnISBN  BY id_r, users BY id_u;
loc_group = GROUP total   BY location;
```

When I run the command:

```
final = FOREACH loc_group GENERATE
            group as location,
            COUNT(total) as rec_num,
            SUM(total.rating) as book_rating_sum;
```

I get a `Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.` error. I think this is because in the `SUM` statement I am not referring correctly to the `rating` but this is because I am a novice in Pig. What I would like as output is something in the following format:

`(location, counts, sum of ratings score over that location)`

I know this is something really small but I have been fighting with this for some time and I am stuck. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ratings are chararrays, but `SUM` needs numeric input. Either read it as a numeric type in your `LOAD` statement, e.g. `rating: float`, or cast it in your summation, e.g. `SUM((float)total.rating)`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up figure this out myself but forgot to update the question! Thanks!